# How to draw multiple ellipse in the same panel

Tags: c#, graphics

I am trying to draw some ellipse in the same panel, and the coordinators are determined by mouse click. Here is my code, this code can only draw one circle. The newer circle is always updating the older circle on the panel. So there is always only one circle.

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
        Graphics g;
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x,y, 10, 10);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

The correct way is to keep a list of things to draw and whenever that list changes `Invalidate` the control you draw on. All drawing should be in the `Paint` event, using `e.Graphics` there!

This will let you draw many circles:

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();   // List<T> is wonderful !

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     points.Add(e.Location);
     panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     g = e.Graphics;    // only ever use this one for persistent graphics!!
     foreach( Point pt in points)
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X, pt.Y,  10, 10);
}
```

delete them all by

```
points.Clear();
```

Delete the last one by

```
points.Remove(points.Last());
```

For other sizes store `List<Rectangle>` instead. For more complex drawing create a `DrawAction` class of your own to hold pens, colors or even rotations and other shapes etc..